# Are there conditions for a symmetric $MN \times MN$ matrix with $M^2$ positive definite $N \times N$ submatrices is also positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra

A particular statistical inference problem requires the cholesky decomposition of a matrix $\mathbf{G} \in \mathbb{R}^{MN \times MN} $, i.e. the method requires the matrix to be positive definite.
The structure of this matrix is such that there are $M^2$ blocks which are submatrices $\mathbf{G}^{(kl)} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$:

$$
\mathbf{G} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{G}^{(11)} & \dots & \mathbf{G}^{(1M)} \\ 
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\mathbf{G}^{(M1)} & \dots & \mathbf{G}^{(MM)} \end{bmatrix}
$$

The inference problem can be broken down such that the parameters in $\mathbf{G}^{(kl)}$ with $k \neq l$ (i.e. each "off-diagonal block") can be estimated with all $\binom M 2$ combinations computed separately:

$$
\mathbf{G}_2 = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{G}^{(kk)} & \mathbf{G}^{(kl)} \\
\mathbf{G}^{(lk)} & \mathbf{G}^{(ll)} \end{bmatrix}
$$

This imposes that only the $2N \times 2N$ submatrices of $\mathbf{G}$ need to be positive definite, but not necessarily (cholesky decomposition-wise) the entire matrix. I was searching for proof of whether the positive definiteness of all $2N \times 2N$ submatrices implied positive definiteness of the larger matrix.

The second part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2801842/positive-definiteness-of-sub-matrices) shows an example a matrix $\mathbf{M} \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times D}$ which is not positive definite with all $2 \times 2$ submatrices that are.
I find that this can be shown by computing the sum of all $2 \times 2$ submatrices $v^T \mathbf{S}_2 v = \sum_i^D \sum_j^D u_i u_j m_{ij} > 0$ and noting that $u^T \mathbf{M} u = \sum_i^D \sum_j^D u_i u_j m_{ij} - \sum_i^D u_i^2 m_{ii} $.

I think this can be generalized to $2N \times 2N$ blocks in the same way, but it is not clear to me whether there could be additiona constraints that would make the positive definiteness of $\mathbf{G}$ hold. So the questions remain.

**Questions:**

1. Is a matrix $\mathbf{G}$ in general **not** positive definite as a consequences of all possible $\mathbf{G}_2$ being positive definite?
2. If yes, are there constraints under which the opposite will hold?